# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow error c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, overflowexception

Hello i'm using c# to build an application to connect to remote mysql server.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace login
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tryLogin(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Authed!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Auth Failure.");

            }

        }
        public bool tryLogin(string username, string password)
        {
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=myhostname;user=myusername;password=mypassword;database=mydatabase;");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM test WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "';");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read() != false)
            {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return true;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the following error:

"OverflowException was unhandled

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow "

I'm not using any arithmetic operations here. Any help ???

Comment: Could you post the stack trace or other details of the exception? You'll find the exception is occurring in one of the libraries you're calling.

Comment: also, your code is currently exposed to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Off the topic, you might want to take a look at the [using Statement (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @philip kendall

you mean this :

login.exe!login.Form1.tryLogin(string username, string password) Line 39 C#

Comment: In which line this is happening?

Comment: If its an odbc driver, maybe [this question][1] is the same problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545175/idatarecord-isdbnull-causes-an-system-overflowexception-arithmetic-overflow

Comment: @Ajay : what is your Build -> ConfigurationManager - > Platform(AnyCPU/x86) ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `test` table in `mysql server`.

Make sure that all fields have valid values in the `username` and `password` columns.

**UPDATE**

try to include the option `"Use Pipe=false;"`,with your connection string.Then it will opens the connection just fine.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: @Ajay could you put your 'stack trace' on your post ?

Comment: @Ajay you can put a brake point and then get the stack trace when error pops up.And also check my update above.

Comment: when i add Use Pipe=false; in the connection string, it says "Keyword not supported"

Comment: @Ajay you have to put stack trace for get more help.for get stack trace see above comment.

Comment: Ok thanks for all of your help.

It turns out the problem lies with the Mysql connector/net 6.6.4 version.

It dropped support for old password authorization.

So i have to uninstall it and install an older version preferably 6.5.5